# Adding function handles

Tags: matlab, function-handle

I have in MATLAB a cell array `C` containing containing n function handles `@(t)`. I also have a vector `x_star` containing `n` constants. I am now trying to make a new function handle consisting of the function on location `i` in the cell array times the constant on location `i` in the vector. I have been trying with this code but it just outputs "index exceeds matrix dimensions":

```
M= @(t) 0;
for i=1:length(x_star)
M = @(t) M(t)+ C{i}(t)*x_star(i);
end
```

Is it possible to do it like this or is there a more convenient way to do it?

And `x_star` and `C` is defined by:

```
w=2*pi/24; 
C = cell(n,1);       
C{1}=@(t) 1;
for i=2:n
    if (mod(i,2)==0)               
        f = @(t) sin(0.5*i*w*t);
    else
        f = @(t) cos(0.5*(i-1)*w*t);
    end
C{i}=f;
end


 A = zeros(length(t),n);     %% Initialize A-matrix
A(:,1)=C{1};
for i=2:n
        A(:,i)=C{i}(t);
end
x_star = (transpose(A)*A)\transpose(A)*y;   
r_star=y-A*x_star;
```

Comment: Are you sure that `length(C)` is greater than or equal to `length(x_star)`?

Comment: Also you are overwriting `M` every loop iteration. That means only the last instance of `M` will be available for further use.

Comment: @Adriaan I believe that's intentional.

Comment: They have the same length, yes :)

Comment: @Linda - Please show us the code that defines `C` and `x_star`.  It's hard to believe they're the same length if you get that error.

Comment: And yes - the point is to add all of these functions, so that they make up one function :)

Comment: And are you sure this recursive definition of `M` works? `f=@(x) x; f=@(x) f(x)+1` gives me `f = @(x)f(x)+1` as output. **EDIT**: interestingly, the output of `f` will be fine, it will just make the `disp` implicit...

Comment: uhm, it is defined in a pretty long way but sure, I can show you :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak That works because Matlab function handles have a workspace attached to them that takes precedence over all others.  So the assignment `f = @(x) f(x) + 1` creates a handle that stores the definition of `f(x)` at creation time and assigns it to the newly create handle `f`.

Comment: @TroyHaskin thanks for the input, I had no idea.

Comment: What is `y` in your code?

Comment: y is a vector of the same length as t. In my example they both have length 24

Comment: And are you sure that an element of `C{i}` will not make `A` longer along the first dimension? Do check `size(C),size(x_star)` right before your error.

Comment: both are column vectors

Comment: Ok, wait wait wait... The input `t` is a vector?  The beginning definition of your anonymous function only outputs 1 scalar.  Should that be a vector of zeroes instead?

Comment: They both have size (7 1) in my example where n = 7. It doesn't fail until i try to add them in M

Comment: Are you sure that every element of `C` is a function handle? If one were an array, then `C{i}(t)` would refer to element number `t`, giving unexpected results.

Comment: hmmm... I can try to show how C is defined to :)

Comment: So...have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: There are some weird things. You should have `A(:,i)=C{1}(t);` with a dummy argument `t`. And `C{1}` should return a vector of length `length(t)`, like so: `C{1}=@(t) ones(length(t),1);`

Comment: oh...my...god... That actually worked..

Comment: Also, if I have this right, you can replace those loops with `A = @(t) [ones(numel(t),1),sin(w/2*t*(k - (mod(k,2)~=0)) + pi/2*ones(numel(t),1)*(mod(k,2)~=0))];
` as long as `k` is a row vector and `t` is a column vector.